# JOIN and ORDER BY - mysql_query

Tags: mysql, join

I have a friends-script and I show friends on list, but I want to order them by their `last active`. I have this code

```sql
SELECT user_one, user_two FROM frnds WHERE user_one='$my_id' OR user_two='$my_id'
```

table frnds

```
|id|user_one|user_two|
| 1|       1|      19|
| 2|       4|       1|
| 3|       9|     403|`
```

`lastactive` is in `users` table.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```sql
SELECT u.name friend_name, u.lastactive
  FROM
(
  SELECT IF(user_one = ?, user_two, user_one) friend
    FROM frnds
   WHERE ? IN(user_one, user_two) 
) f JOIN users u
    ON f.friend = u.id
 ORDER BY u.lastactive DESC;
```

or

```sql
SELECT u.name friend_name, u.lastactive
  FROM 
(
  SELECT user_one friend
    FROM frnds
   WHERE user_two = ?
  UNION ALL
  SELECT user_two
    FROM frnds
   WHERE user_one = ?
) f JOIN users u
    ON f.friend = u.id
 ORDER BY u.lastactive DESC;
```

***Note:** in both queries `?` is a placeholder for `$my_id`*

Sample output (in both cases):

```
| FRIEND_NAME |                      LASTACTIVE |
|-------------|---------------------------------|
|     User 19 |    March, 03 2014 20:30:57+0000 |
|      User 4 | February, 24 2014 20:30:57+0000 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf592/11)** demo